# vue-awesome-swiper. Слайдер с отступом

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider

[У меня в проекте установлен vue-awesome-swiper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-awesome-swiper)

Опции которые мне понадобились для определения слайдера.

swiperOption: {
loop: false,
autoplay: false,
slidesPerView: 3,
centeredSlides: true,
spaceBetween: 30,
}

Но мне нужно, что бы первый слайдер был с отступом в 16 px.
Если я на карточку ставлю margin-left: 16px; у меня последний слайд обрезается на 16 пикселей. Не хватает длинны.

Как можно сделать такой отступ ? Или как можно указать длинну слайдера  + 16px что бы последний слайд полностью вмещался ?